# Easy way to delete rows that have a certain value

Tags: r, subset, delete-row

I have a data set with several columns and I'm working on it using R. Most of those columns have missing data, which was set as a value -200. What I want to do is to delete all the rows that have -200 in any of the columns. Is there an easy way to do this other than going by each column at a time? Can I delete all rows that a value of -200 all at once?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can do it with `rowSums`, something like `df[rowSums(df == -200) == 0,]` or you can read it specifying to convert `-200` to `NA`, and proceed as usual

Comment: @Sotos thank you so much, that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyverse` option would be

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   filter_all(all_vars(. != -200))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(-200, 1, 2, 3), v2 = c(1, -200, 2, 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rowSums()`, i.e.

```
df[rowSums(df == -200) == 0,]
```